# Selenium's ChromeDriver and IEDriver fail to launch using WIndows 7 / TFS

Tags: c#

I'm using Selenium within our WIndows 7 / TFS / C# project. 
It successfully launches the Firefox driver, but fails to launch the 
Chrome and IE drivers. I can successfully instantiate the driver like 
so:

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

But when I try to navigate to a URL:

```
GuiOperations.goToUrl("http://viamplutotpqa.northamerica.vi.local");
```

It fails with a "TypeInitializationException". 
Any ideas? Is this just some weird configuration problem on my 
workstation?

Answer (score 0):

Only the Firefox driver is included with Selenium by default. You will have to download the other drivers and include them with your release by dropping them alongside the selenium binary.

- [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
- [IE Driver and others](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)